# What would be historically correct manpower/citysize/tax values for the Indonesian islands?

Tags: mods, europa-universalis-3

What would be historically correct manpower/citysize/tax values for the Indonesian islands at or around the game start of Europa Universalis III in 1399?

The game as shipped tends to under-value "native" population numbers significantly outside Europe, and it tends to base those on post-colonial numbers in a lot of cases. Of course, with the game being as highly moddable as it is, it's no problem to modify those numbers to the correct ones, and to add new provinces as necessary. In particular, I'm interested in the areas around the [province IDs](http://www.paradoxian.org/eu3wiki/List_of_provinces) 617-659 (so roughly the areas of today's Indonesia, Philippines and other smaller states on the neighbouring islands) and their (raw) values for `base_tax`, `manpower`and `citysize` for the civilised areas (most if not all of the coast) and `native_size` for the "wild" areas inland.

Historical references which can be used to derive those values are welcome as well.

---

Since the History.SE site opened now, the question about the real-world demographic and economic situation in this area has its own question now there: "[What were the demographics and economics of south-east Asian islands around year 1400?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/688/what-were-the-demographics-and-economics-of-south-east-asian-islands-around-year)" Should there data available be sufficient to answer this question about in-game data values and nobody post an answer until then, I'll post one answer myself.

Comment: Though I understand you are asking in the context of a video game, I think neither getting historic information, nor mod development advice, is on topic here.

Comment: @Oak: Well, looking through the [mods] tag, there have been a few questions about "How do I mod ...", so it *might* be off-topic, but I'm not sure. As for the historical information, I guess players interested in the answers wouldn't need a lengthy explanations on what the in-game values *mean*, as opposed to every other site on the SE network and they would be also more interested in the answers, but if there's a better site to move it to, feel free to do it.

Comment: You're probably more likely to get a good answers to this question on the [Paradox forums for EU3](http://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?323-Europa-Universalis-III). There's a lively community of players and modding folk there with a mutual interest in historical knowledge of this kind. They even have their own [User Mods forum](http://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?357-EU3-User-Modifications) for exactly this kind of question. Good luck! :)